# as.numeric creates NA when there are blank spaces

Tags: r, na, dplyr

When using `mutate_at` to change variables in my data to either character, numeric or factors, I have issues with the numeric ones:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- c('V1', 'V2')
c <- c('V3', 'V4')
n <- c('V5', 'V6')

data <- data.frame(V1 = c(0,2,""),
                   V2 = c("", 3, 4),
                   V3 = c(1, 2, 3),
                   V4 = c(0, 0, ""),
                   V5 = c(-1, -1, ""),
                   V6 = c(0, 1, ""))

data <- data %>% 
        mutate_at(f, as.factor) %>%
        mutate_at(c, as.character) %>%
        mutate_at(n, as.numeric)
```

In this specific case, I get as a result something weird:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
  1  0     1  0  2  2
  2  1  3  2  0  2  3
  3     4  3     1  1
```

In other cases, as in my original data, I get `NA` in place of blank spaces.

Can someone help?

Comment: Add `mutate_all(as.character)` at the beginning of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `readr::parse_guess` to do suitable conversions?

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
data %>% mutate_all(~parse_guess(as.character(.x)))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1  0 NA  1  0 -1  0
#2  2  3  2  0 -1  1
#3 NA  4  3 NA NA NA
```